# How to get the common elements of two lists and store it in a new list without duplication

Tags: c++, pointers

I have allocated two arrays in the memory using pointers and I also have a function to get the user's input of elements and store it in the arrays. My only problem is I do not know how to find the common element(s) in the two arrays and store it in another new array. How do I do it?

I have already tried comparing each element of the first array to each of the elements of the second array, and if they are equal to each other, then I should store it in the new array. But still, this does not seem for me an efficient code.

```
int *j = new int[n];
getList(j, n);

int *k = new int[m];
getList(k, m);

/* how would I create a new array to 
store the common elements of the 
previous two arrays and display its elements? */
```

Comment: C++ have many nice [standard algorithm functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), including some for handling [set operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm#Set_operations_.28on_sorted_ranges.29). For example one to [create an intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection), which seems to be what you want.

Comment: The key to doing this efficiently is to sort the elements first. This lets you use a single loop, instead of nested loops to get the intersection.

Comment: @john sorting itself would be some form of the nested looping, either directly or via recursion.

Comment: @SergeyA But sorting is still better than the quadratic time of nested loops.

Comment: @john, why? you can just intersect as a set, with Log(N) complexity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly want to use [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) from the `<algorithm>` header for this. Remember that raw pointers to contiguous memory qualify as input iterators, hence:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> result;

// Make sure that [j, j + n) and [k, k + m) are sorted 

std::set_intersection(j, j + n, k, k + m, std::back_inserter(result));
```

Note that as @john pointed out in the comments, this algorithm requires that both input sequences are sorted.

If the input ranges aren't sorted anyway and you're worried about performance, you might want to read [this blog post](https://cukic.co/2018/06/03/set-intersection-in-cxx/) for an alternative.

Comment: Yes, but you should mention that the arrays must be sorted before using `set_intersection`

Comment: @john True, thanks for the suggestion. I'll improve the answer.

Comment: Just replace the comment with `std::sort(result.begin(); result.end());` in case you want to sort it.

Comment: @Andra No, that sorts the result, not the input. The input must be sorted _before_ calling `set_intersection`.